Is it possible to reduce latency from safari or quicktime to cmaf low latency hls playback URL?
I made a play URL based on cmaf ll-hls in wowza.
In the html5 player and the chrome hls player, it was seen that the latency was applied for 4 to 5 seconds.
However, the latency of safari, quicktime is still applied for 12 to 18 seconds.
Can't save latency on default browser and quicktime with ccmafl-hls play url?
Or am I making the m3u8 wrong and it doesn't apply?
(safari 15.1 version , mac)
Any help would be greatly appreciated.. I've been struggling for 2 months.
Below is the m3u8 that I made.
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:6
#EXT-X-SERVER-CONTROL:CAN-BLOCK-RELOAD=YES,PART-HOLD-BACK=3.009,CAN-SKIP-UNTIL=42.0
#EXT-X-INDEPENDENT-SEGMENTS
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:7
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:21
#EXT-X-PART-INF:PART-TARGET=1.0
#EXT-X-RENDITION-REPORT:URI="chunklist_b1000000_vo_sfm4s.m3u8",LAST-MSN=26,LAST-PART=0
#EXT-X-RENDITION-REPORT:URI="chunklist_b600000_vo_sfm4s.m3u8",LAST-MSN=26,LAST-PART=0
#EXT-X-RENDITION-REPORT:URI="chunklist_b96000_ao_sfm4s_sleng_t64RW5nbGlzaA==.m3u8",LAST-MSN=26,LAST-PART=0
#EXT-X-MAP:URI="header-u9f4vz01t_b800000_vo_sfm4s_m3u8.cmfv"
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2024-08-09T06:49:13.781+00:00
#EXTINF:6.0,
media-u9f4vz01t_b800000_vo_sfm4s_21_m3u8.cmfv
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2024-08-09T06:49:19.802+00:00
#EXTINF:6.0,
media-u9f4vz01t_b800000_vo_sfm4s_22_m3u8.cmfv
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2024-08-09T06:49:25.759+00:00
#EXT-X-PART:DURATION=1.0,URI="media-u9f4vz01t_b800000_vo_sfm4s_23.0_m3u8.cmfv",INDEPENDENT=YES
#EXT-X-PART:DURATION=1.0,URI="media-u9f4vz01t_b800000_vo_sfm4s_23.1_m3u8.cmfv",INDEPENDENT=YES
#EXT-X-PART:DURATION=1.0,URI="media-u9f4vz01t_b800000_vo_sfm4s_23.2_m3u8.cmfv",INDEPENDENT=YES
#EXT-X-PART:DURATION=1.0,URI="media-u9f4vz01t_b800000_vo_sfm4s_23.3_m3u8.cmfv",INDEPENDENT=YES
#EXT-X-PART:DURATION=1.0,URI="media-u9f4vz01t_b800000_vo_sfm4s_23.4_m3u8.cmfv",INDEPENDENT=YES
#EXT-X-PART:DURATION=1.0,URI="media-u9f4vz01t_b800000_vo_sfm4s_23.5_m3u8.cmfv",INDEPENDENT=YES
#EXTINF:6.0,
media-u9f4vz01t_b800000_vo_sfm4s_23_m3u8.cmfv
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2024-08-09T06:49:31.771+00:00
#EXT-X-PART:DURATION=1.0,URI="media-u9f4vz01t_b800000_vo_sfm4s_24.0_m3u8.cmfv",INDEPENDENT=YES
#EXT-X-PART:DURATION=1.0,URI="media-u9f4vz01t_b800000_vo_sfm4s_24.1_m3u8.cmfv",INDEPENDENT=YES
#EXT-X-PART:DURATION=1.0,URI="media-u9f4vz01t_b800000_vo_sfm4s_24.2_m3u8.cmfv",INDEPENDENT=YES
#EXT-X-PART:DURATION=1.0,URI="media-u9f4vz01t_b800000_vo_sfm4s_24.3_m3u8.cmfv",INDEPENDENT=YES
#EXT-X-PART:DURATION=1.0,URI="media-u9f4vz01t_b800000_vo_sfm4s_24.4_m3u8.cmfv",INDEPENDENT=YES
#EXT-X-PART:DURATION=1.0,URI="media-u9f4vz01t_b800000_vo_sfm4s_24.5_m3u8.cmfv",INDEPENDENT=YES
#EXTINF:6.0,
media-u9f4vz01t_b800000_vo_sfm4s_24_m3u8.cmfv
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2024-08-09T06:49:37.729+00:00
#EXT-X-PART:DURATION=1.0,URI="media-u9f4vz01t_b800000_vo_sfm4s_25.0_m3u8.cmfv",INDEPENDENT=YES
#EXT-X-PART:DURATION=1.0,URI="media-u9f4vz01t_b800000_vo_sfm4s_25.1_m3u8.cmfv",INDEPENDENT=YES
#EXT-X-PART:DURATION=1.0,URI="media-u9f4vz01t_b800000_vo_sfm4s_25.2_m3u8.cmfv",INDEPENDENT=YES
#EXT-X-PART:DURATION=1.0,URI="media-u9f4vz01t_b800000_vo_sfm4s_25.3_m3u8.cmfv",INDEPENDENT=YES
#EXT-X-PART:DURATION=1.0,URI="media-u9f4vz01t_b800000_vo_sfm4s_25.4_m3u8.cmfv",INDEPENDENT=YES
#EXT-X-PART:DURATION=1.0,URI="media-u9f4vz01t_b800000_vo_sfm4s_25.5_m3u8.cmfv",INDEPENDENT=YES
#EXTINF:6.0,
media-u9f4vz01t_b800000_vo_sfm4s_25_m3u8.cmfv
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2024-08-09T06:49:43.747+00:00
#EXT-X-PART:DURATION=1.0,URI="media-u9f4vz01t_b800000_vo_sfm4s_26.0_m3u8.cmfv",INDEPENDENT=YES
#EXT-X-PRELOAD-HINT:TYPE=PART,URI="media-u9f4vz01t_b800000_vo_sfm4s_26.1_m3u8.cmfv"

If the m3u8 file is wrong, please let me know why it is wrong
I'd appreciate it if you could recommend an ios native app to test the cmaf ll-hls playback URL generated by wowza.
If safari, quicktime basically doesn't apply cmaf ll-hls, I'd really appreciate it if you could let me know what options or tasks I need to do when I develop an ios player.
